# What does it mean that file IO binary flag is only relevant on Windows

Tags: ruby, file-handling

I was reading a question and one of the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/131001/536607) mentioned that "The binary flag is only relevant on Windows". Given the context of the question and answer, I interpret this statement as `on non-windows machines, we don't need to specify text or binary mode when doing file IO`

The context of the question is to read all bytes of a file into a string (presumably preserving bytes). It seems very relevant to me whether I'm reading the data as text or bytes, since reading text involves dealing with encoding. If I'm reading a UTF-16 file, for example, what I get in text mode is much different from what I get in binary mode.

Assuming my interpretation of the statement is correct, is it unnecessary to specify whether a file should be opened in text or binary mode on non-windows machines? That is, all files are read in binary mode by default.

Otherwise, what could the statement be referring to? (the comment received a number of upvotes so presumably this is not just one person's opinion)

Comment: Daniel (the person posting the comment) is an active user; he was on the site 3 hours ago.  Why don't you post a comment asking for clarification?

Comment: This is a reasonable question, though, assuming it isn't a duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

The "binary" flag exists for the `fopen()` function call in the C standard library. On my nearest Linux system, the documentation states:

> The mode string can also include the letter 'b' either as a last character or as a character between the characters in any of the two-character strings described above.  This is strictly for compatibility  with C89 and has no effect; the 'b' is ignored on all POSIX conforming systems, including Linux.  (Other systems may treat text files and binary files differently, and adding the 'b' may be a good idea if you do I/O to a binary file and expect that your program may be ported to non-Unix environments.)

The C standard library functions do not deal with text encodings. Data read from or written to files are bytes. On some systems such as Windows, the line-endings are conventionally `\r\n` but on POSIX systems, the line-endings are just `\n`. This is one of the things that the "binary" flag controls (another thing may be the details of end-of-file handling).

However, in Ruby, the [IO::new](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/IO.html#method-c-new) function treats the "b" flag as follows (emphasis mine):

> "b"  Binary file mode
>        Suppresses EOL <-> CRLF conversion on Windows. **And
>        sets external encoding to ASCII-8BIT unless explicitly
>        specified**.

This means that additionally, Ruby sets the character encoding depending on whether the "b" flag is included. This means that its use is *not* specific to Windows, and can affect the behaviour of your program even on a POSIX system.